# How can I find my current login time on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp

Is there any thing in Windows XP that can tell me the log in the time for my current login.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about Control-Alt-Delete?
[image]

Where it says logon date that should be the time and date the user logged on.

Another option is to use Windows Utility quser.exe, which comes with Windows 2003 but works fine under Windows XP. I found a download link [here](http://www.alexander.com/SymServe/quser.exe/3B7D83387000/quser.exe). You might also find it's already on XP in C:\Windows\System32\DLLCache.

You use it like this:

```
quser.exe yourusername
```

The output looks like this:

```
 USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
 >John                 console             0  Active            .  11/12/2010 06:36
```

Answer (score 4):

In `cmd.exe`, type

```
net user "Your Username"
```

Look for the line starting with "`Last logon`".

Comment: that seems to work only for local accounts, not when the computer is on a domain

Comment: @nmuntz I don't have a domain handy (or a Windows system, for that matter), but maybe you only need to prefix the username or something similar? `net user` alone lists the users.

Comment: I found it. The correct command is net user /domain username when the computer is on a domain. However The Last Logon line is incorrect in this case. It is giving me yesterday as the last logon . not sure why :)

Answer (score 3):

Start/Settings/Control Panel/Administrative Tools/Event Viewer
Under Security you will find login time etc.

Comment: i did't find the time it show an empty field and nothing else

Comment: All information under "Security" has a timestamp. Check out the column "Time".

Comment: you can see in screen shot i added

Comment: This seems to be the only option that works for me, since I am remoted into the computer from another computer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can try psloggedon utility at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897545.aspx

And you can use the time provided against your user name.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got logging enabled?

Administrative tools > Local Security Policy > Local Policies > Audit Policy > Audit Logon Events

Answer (score 0):

Click on Start > Search, select All Files and Folders and type 'Event Viewer' in the Search box.  Your search should return a shortcut to the Event Viewer.

Open the file, select folder 'System' and sort on column 'Source'.  Look for 'eventlog' and this will show you all of your logon and logoff times from Day 1.